# firefox: The connection to websocket was interrupted while the page was loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, websocket

i have the following code:

```js
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/websocket");
ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
};

function send() {
    ws.send('test');

}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", send);

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <head>
    <script src="ws-client.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" id="t" value=""/>
      <button type="submit">send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and i get "The connection to ws://localhost:8080/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading. ws-client.js:2:0" when trying to send the message to the server.

this code works fine under Chrome.

and at my server side, i can see that the handshake is successful, and the server have received the message and sent the response.

here is the handshake:

```
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/websocket
Request Method:     GET
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols

Request Headers:
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/36.0
Upgrade:    websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Version:  13
Sec-WebSocket-Key:  HuqIhI8DVOJu7PvhnHafJg==
Pragma: no-cache
Origin: null
Host:   localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Response Headers:
Upgrade:    websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:   8ZD23MLEK3DgLPuEoRl+6UPtdg8=
Connection: Upgrade
```

do you know what's wrong? thanks!

Comment: Your snippet references localhost and as result doesn't run out of the box.  Why do you think your problem is described by this error? it is a standard notification which happens when you have a socket connection and reload the page. The connection from previous page is actually broken while the new page context is loading. Usually this message is on top of console for this session

Comment: you are right, Kirill. it's because the page is refreshed when submitting a form in firefox, if i don't use <form>, then it works. thanks!